# How to render a loader while I upload file on firebase using flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I want to upload pdf files on flutter and I have written a function to implement this and on button press I want to run this function to upload the pdf but It will take some time to upload so till then I want to show a loader.

```
Future savePdf() async {
    StorageReference storageReference;
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    String uid = user.uid.toString();
    print(uid);
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(uid);
    final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(file);
    final StorageTaskSnapshot downloadUrl = (await uploadTask.onComplete);

    docurl = (await downloadUrl.ref.getDownloadURL());
    await firestoreInstance.collection('Resumes').document(uid).setData(
      {
        'score': 'Scoring under Process...',
        'pdf': docurl.toString(),
        'feedback': 'Feedback under Process,Please hold tight!',
      },
    ).then((result)=>
    setState((){
      isuploaded=true;
    })
    
    );
  }
```

This is my function `savepdf` to upload pdf.
Now Here is my button which on pressed has to show a loader while uploading.

```
onPressed: () async {
            await savePdf();
}
```

How do I show a loader while I upload the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could us a `isLoading` bool and then:

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  setState(() => isLoading = true);
  await savePdf();
  setState(() => isLoading = false);
}
```

Then in your widget tree:

```dart
...
if (isLoading)
   CircularProgressIndicator();
...
```